# calling controls in Parent window

Tags: c#, wpf

i used vb.net before and want to explore c#. (they said c# is better than vb.net) but anyways... i used this code below from vb.net calling controls in parent window.

```
Dim strWindowToLookFor As String = GetType(MainWindowForm).Name
Me.Close()
Dim win = (From w In Application.Current.Windows Where DirectCast(w, Window).GetType.Name = strWindowToLookFor Select w).FirstOrDefault
If win IsNot Nothing Then
    DirectCast(win, MainWindowForm).imglogin.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
    DirectCast(win, MainWindowForm).Focus()
End If
```

i found this code before in other forums and helps me a lot in vb.net... but now i want to use this code in c# for me to call controls... so i converted it using SharpDevelop ( a good software)....

```
        string strWindowToLookFor = typeof(MainWindowForm).Name;
        this.Close();
        var win = (from w in Application.Current.Windowswhere ((Window)w).GetType().Name == strWindowToLookForw).FirstOrDefault;
        if (win != null) {
            ((MainWindowForm)win).imglogin.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            ((MainWindowForm)win).Focus();
        }
```

the problem is it gives me an error:

**Error 1   Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Windows.WindowCollection'.  'Where' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'w'.**

Error #1 highlighted the Application.Current.Windows.

**Error 2   A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really need to use reflection here. You could try something much simpler:

```
var mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindowForm>()
                                            .FirstOrDefault();

if (mainWindow != null)
{
   //Visibility stuff goes here
}
```

Comment: yezzzzz!!! thank you so much pickles... thanks for your code... :) you give me hope in c#... (woooh! so hard c# is.. but i now learn to love it..! lol!) and also to sir steve and sir simon thanks also.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from w in Application.Current.Windowswhere

from w in Application.Current.Windows where



var win = (from w in Application.Current.Windows where ((Window)w).GetType().Name == strWindowToLookForw select w).FirstOrDefault()
```

Edit: Above should be the fully modified line. Added the space for the "where" condition and added the "select" statement.

A word of caution: Tools and samples are meant to aid understanding, they're not a substitute for it. Be sure to read and understand what the samples you come across, and tools generate/convert.

And C# is not "better" than VB.Net, it is a different language on the same platform. Of course, a lot of people will have the opinion it is better. :)

Comment: Perhaps add the "select w" at the end of your example :)

Comment: Possibly not, it's using a FirstOrDefault so it will probably work. Frankly mixing the linq keywords and methods gives me the shudders. (pick one or the other)
Edit: Ah yes, just re-read his question, 2nd error needs the Select. Will update.

Comment: yes i did that one. but still the error is still the same. im sorry i forgot to put space between .Windows and where. sir simon, sir steve can you give me a revised program of this?

Comment: sir steve i copied your solution and still it gives me the same error #1. still the Application.Current.Windows is underlined wit red.. means there's something wrong with "Application.Current.Windows"

Comment: @user1405327 Without access to your code, there is absolutely no way we can ascertain what the issue is with Application.Current.Windows.

Comment: Is this a WPF application or a Windows Forms application? Application.Current.Windows is only available in WPF. (nvm, seen it's been answered)